# Should our application store the image properties in a database? Or should the application generate them at runtime?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So my application is simple. It is a laravel 5 framework running a desktop template website.

My question is a performance question. Should we store the image properties in a database like MySQL or should we just generate them on the fly? The properties would be simply image resolution, image file size, image color properties, also file extension.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this question is too broad and based on opinions. might be closed soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is never generate images on fly when performance is a concern, rather generate different sizes once, save them in certain folder say `uploads\images` or read the image properties once during upload(to avoid doing so on each image request) and store properties in a DB table.

Comment: For clarification, I won't be generating the images on the fly, was simply going to read their properties on the fly, would that still be just as bad? I am currently leaning more toward storing all properties to the DB on the upload.

Comment: Doing it once during the upload is still more efficient, my opinion dough

Comment: The question was about the properties/meta data of an image. If you generate on the fly, you will going to read the file on every request. I not sure why some professional down vote my answer, but take this recommendation, store the meta somewhere else that is easy to query.

Answer (score -1):

Store in MySQL, as long as the query is efficient and record is not very large (a few 10 million to hundred millions), you will be fine.

Comment: Have you measured the two approaches and come to the conclusion that this is the best solution? If not then you should refrain from telling people what the best solution is.

Comment: Storing picture meta is fairy common practice,is this the best solution, ofcourse not, u need a highly specialize server to handle large amount of picture data, even cloud storage will be a problem. As we assume this question is being ask only when developing on medium to low usage, a common practice is always recommended.